# WPF: Trying to provide dynamic data upon creation

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm hoping I'm about a concept and half close to here...

I want the caller (a non-WPF class) to give my WPF the data to display.  So, apparently not defined in a XmlDataProvider nor an ObjectProvider.

For purposes of example, I've modified this [demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx).  I've taken references to the 'Person' element in the XmlDataProvider.  Instead, I've made a couple of very simple classes:

EDIT: This is now changed to Properties (no change in output, though):

```
public class ExpenseData
{
    private String expenseType;
    private String expenseAmount;

    public String ExpenseType
    {
        get { return expenseType; }
        set { expenseType = value; }
    }

    public String ExpenseAmount
    {
        get { return expenseAmount; }
        set { expenseAmount = value; }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private ExpenseData expense;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public String Department
    {
        get { return department; }
        set { department = value; }
    }

    public ExpenseData Expense
    {
        get { return expense; }
        set { expense = value; }
    }
}
```

Then when I call my WPF, I setup the data like so:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExpenseIt9.Person person = new ExpenseIt9.Person();

        person.Name = "Jimmy";
        person.Department = "Sales";
        person.Expense = new ExpenseIt9.ExpenseData();
        person.Expense.ExpenseAmount = "50";
        person.Expense.ExpenseType = "Travel";
        // View Expense Report
        ExpenseReportPage expenseReportPage = new ExpenseReportPage(person);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(expenseReportPage);
    }
```

It may be important to note the WPF constructur (same as original sample):

```
// Custom constructor to pass expense report data
public ExpenseReportPage(object data):this()
{
    // Bind to expense report data.
    this.DataContext = data;
}
```

Upon running this, none of my data shows up.  What am I missing?

EDIT: Here is the view (same as original):

```
    <Page x:Class="ExpenseIt.ExpenseReportPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="500"
    Title="ExpenseIt - View Expense Report">

    <Grid>

        <!--Templates to display expense report data-->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!-- Reason item template -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="typeItemTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@ExpenseType}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <!-- Amount item template -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="amountItemTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@ExpenseAmount}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>


        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="watermark.png" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Label Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource headerTextStyle}">
            Expense Report For:
        </Label>
        <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 


            <!-- Name -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}">Name:</Label>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- Department -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}">Department:</Label>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="{Binding XPath=@Department}"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">



                <!-- Expense type and Amount table -->
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Expense}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ExpenseType" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ExpenseType}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ExpenseAmount}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Comment: Never set control's own `DataContext` in constructors, this may lead to non-obvious binding errors.

Comment: Wow. Really?  That code snippet is unedited from the original msdn sample.  Then again, it wouldn't be the first time I've seen bad practices shown in demos.

Comment: Setting `this.DataContext` from control constructor makes it impossible to easily bind properties of this control from outside. For example in your case if you will write `<ExpenseReportPage SomeProperty="{Binding Path=SomePath}" />` I would expect this `SomePath` to be searched in `DataContext` of parent control of ExpenseReportPage, but instead it will take your `DataContext` into account. If you really need to set some `DataContext` for your control then set it on one level below. Usually all controls have some `layoutRoot` control inside which has everything else nested.

Comment: @Jahmic: Fields cannot be bound, only properties can be used for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with a fresh demo sample and things are now working fine.  This was the [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MovingTowardWpfBinding.aspx).  This seemed more direct at what I was trying to do.  Not sure of what the key differences were of the working and non-working samples.  Perhaps the 'base.DataContext' setting.

Nevertheless, as things get more complex, I'll probably be using the MVVM design pattern more and more.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included your view code, but there are few things wrong here. Firstly, you cannot bind to fields, so you should change all of your public fields to properties instead. Also, if you wish to change these values in code and have the changes reflected in the UI, then you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also, you should have a look into the [MVVM design pattern](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx) for a number of benefits.

Comment: Ah, of course, Properties instead of fields.  my bad.  The rest looks promising... Will let you know how it turns out.